# what happened to my tracking id in google analytics

Tags: android, google-analytics

i registered some project in google analytics before and they work fine
but today i can`t find them !

```
<string name="ga_trackingId">UA-73328744-1</string>
<string name="ga_trackingId">UA-73328744-2</string>
<string name="ga_trackingId">UA-73328744-3</string>
<string name="ga_trackingId">UA-78907653-1</string>
```

what happened to them ! 
how can i return them back ?
[image]

Comment: I am not really sure what you are asking. Your screenshot is of the Google Analytics Demo Account, so if you can't find your reports it's probably because your are looking into the wrong account. The account selector is at the top left (where it currently says "Google Merchandise Store").

Comment: thank you for answer : yeah i know its Demo but it added after all i looking in google Analytics And Google Document , my project always  has been shown after i login with my gmail , i am sure the account selector was empty and now just show Demo !

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure this is what you're looking for, or if it'll even be helpful.

My experience with Google Analytics, great service that it is, is that they change their format / layout waaaay too often. When they change a layout I usually have to drill down deeper to find the things that used to be obvious, or nearer to the surface (friendlier to the user, dig?).

Just a few days ago I had a similar experience. I "looked like" the sites I had registered were gone. In reality they were only "hidden" because of new defaults for how analytics comes up (for me, at least) over the last time I had visited it.